# How to perform an action if nothing is emitted from the observable after X seconds?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactivex

I am subscribed to an observable, but I only want to listen to it for say 3 seconds. If nothing is emitted after 3 seconds, I want to perform a particular action. I have looked at lot of places, but can't seem to find an answer.

An example of it is listening for a web response for 3 seconds. If nothing is received after 3 seconds, I want to print out "Timed out" etc.

How can one achieve this in RxJava?

Comment: Do you want to keep printing "Timed out" after every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [timeout](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html) operator?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    requestToApi()
            .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(
                    System.out::println,
                    error -> System.out.println("Timed out")
            );

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

private static Observable<String> requestToApi() {
    // simulate a request to an API that will take 5 seconds to return a response
    return Observable.just("response").delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```